# How to tune Local Binary Pattern?

Tags: image-processing, textures, conv-neural-network, scikit-image

I am using `LBP` on `grayscale` images for facial expression recognition task. How can I figure out the best parameters (`number of neighbour set points`, and `radius of circle`) for `LBP` which will be used as the input of my CNN?

p.s. Using `skimage`'s `LBP` implementation

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use a CNN directly for this task, but in general, for any learning task, you should use cross-validation to estimate task performance. scikit-learn has excellent documentation on model selection, cross-validation, and parameter search:

- [Cross-validation module](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)
- [Model selection tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html)
- [Grid search and other strategies](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html)

More advanced model selection includes Bayesian parameter search, for which the modules [hyperopt](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt) and [Optuna](https://github.com/pfnet/optuna) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment; but actually I am looking for the optimization of LBP.

Comment: The principle is exactly the same: find a metric you care about, then use cross-validation to tune the parameters of the pipeline. It's irrelevant whether you are tuning the number of trees in a random forest, the number of hidden layers in a network, or the input parameters to LBP.